# Display website as screensaver

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, screensaver

How can I make my screensaver, in OSX Mountain Lion, to display a website?

Not a static one, a dynamic, changing website that uses HTML5.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/160949/how-do-i-set-my-wallpaper-to-a-web-page-on-mac-os-x

Comment: This is not a duplicate. He is asking about a screensaver, not the desktop wallpaper.

Answer (score 0):

There's a freeware app called [websaver](https://code.google.com/p/websaver/) created for just this purpose. I don't think it will work with Mavericks, but you shouldn't have any trouble getting it to work with Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 0):

The little app [WebViewScreenSaver](https://github.com/liquidx/webviewscreensaver) works for me.

The site finds my answer to be sub-par, though there's not much I can add; It's a simple install, and it allows you to set any URL as your screensaver. Seems to have been around for a while, and still works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).